# What are the use-cases of "complete-class context"? What's the benefit that a "complete-class context" provides?

Tags: c++, class

In current working draft, the definition of complete-class context is: (§ 11.4.1 [class.mem.general]/7):

> A complete-class context of a class (template) is a
>
> - (7.1) function body ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - (7.2) default argument ([dcl.fct.default]),
> - (7.3) default template argument ([temp.param]),
> - (7.4) noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - (7.5) default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class or class template.

In fact, I don't understand the intention of this wording. What are the use-cases of "complete-class context"? What's the benefit that a "complete-class context" provides? So any further explanation will be appreciated.

For instance, what does mean that a function body is a complete-class context? Is this mean, for example, ..

```
struct X {
  void f(){
   X x{};
  }
};
```

.. that I can create an `X` object within the function body of `X::f`? if yes, does it mean anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we did not have a complete-class context then we could not write a class like

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() { std::cout << kitty; }
    std::string kitty = "meow";
};
```

because `kitty` isn't known about until after `bar` is defined.  You would have to write the class like

```
struct foo
{
    void bar();
    std::string kitty = "meow";
};

void foo::bar() { std::cout << kitty; }
```

Comment: "_The class is regarded as complete within its complete-class contexts [..]_" just means that an instance of this class can only appear within complete-class contexts? (i.e, within function bodies and default argument, etc)

Comment: @Jamoiuztowsxclolor It means that you can use all members of the class in the completed class context, even if they have not been declared or defined yet.

Comment: So what about my example above? Why I'm allowed to create `X` objects within the function body?

Comment: What about it?  You are in the complete class context so you can create objects of the class type.  Like I said you can use **all members**, that includes constructors.

Comment: _"You are in the complete class context so you can create objects of the class type."_ But the ending `}` has not been reached yet.

Comment: @Jamoiuztowsxclolor the `}` for the end of the function or the `}` for the end of the class?

Comment: The end of the class has not been reached yet.

Comment: @Jamoiuztowsxclolor That's why we have the completed class context.  It lets us use the class as if it was complete, i.e. fully defined, even before it is.