# function with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Given the following code:

```
struct A {
   constexpr static auto e() { return 0; }
   void f(int V1 = e()) { int V2 = e(); }
};
```

I've got the following clang error:

```
error: function 'e' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
   void f(int V1 = e()) { int V2 = e(); }
                  ~~^~~
```

My understanding is that both function-body and default argument are [complete-class contexts](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#6) in which the class and its member definitions, in those contexts, are considered completely defined.

Within the function body, I've *used* the function `A::e` as an initializer for variable `V2`. There's no error at this point which makes me sure that, within the function body, the function `A::e` is considered completely defined.

Within the function parameter list, I've *used* `A::e` as a default argument for parameter `V1`. By definition, a default argument is considered a complete-class context. At this point, I'm getting an error stating that `A::e` is used before it's defined. But per my understanding, `A::e` *is* considered defined in any complete-class context.

This is somehow weird for me because function bodies and default arguments are complete-class contexts. I really don't see any difference between both because in both contexts, the member function `X::e` is fully-defined.

I'm not sure that [[dcl.spec.auto]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.spec.auto#general-11) is what causes the error here. It says:

> If the name of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type appears in an expression, the program is ill-formed [..]

If `[dcl.spec.auto]/11` is what causes the error, the initialization of variable `V2` shall also be ill-formed because if, that's the case, the name `e` of the initializer `e()` is a name of an entity with an undeduced placeholder type.

So, **my question is**: what is the wording of the standard that prohibits `e()` to be a default argument for `V1` *and*, at the same time, allows `e()` to be an initializer for `V2`?

Comment: Maybe because this looks like a duplicate account of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73984055/scope-of-member-declarations-within-the-class . This is the fourth question(2 of which were deleted from the old account). All questions are very similar and about complete class context.

Comment: Closest I can find in the Standard is for template instantiations not being allowed in default arguments: [templ.expl.spec $20](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#20) (Assuming deduction of an `auto` type is much like a template specialization.)

Comment: @AdrianMole : That's correct, but unfortunately that's not the case here. Note also, if I add a non-static data member `M` in class `A` (above) and used `e()` as a default member initializer for `A::M`, this is also an [error](https://godbolt.org/z/vboxfhYf5) even though the [default member initializer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#6.4) is complete-class context.

Comment: @Maria: Ronald is accusing you of being a sock-puppet of the account "Jamoiuztow sxclolor" which asked a number of questions about similar "complete-class context" issues, including [this still visible one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73976245/734069). I don't think this is a duplicate, as it is dealing with a different thing.

Comment: @Eljay: That's not what that paragraph means. That's where the class is considered "complete". The locations of "complete-class contexts" are defined in the previous paragraph.

Comment: @NicolBolas • Argh, yes, I see what you mean.  This is why I've hung up my language lawyer spurs long ago.  I'll delete my incorrect comment referring to class.mem.general#7 so as not to throw off the casual future reader.

Answer (score 6):

There is no obvious reason why, as the OP suggests, being in a complete-class context ought to guarantee that you can use a function with a deduced return type.

The OP writes:

> My understanding is that both function-body and default argument are complete-class contexts in which the class and its member definitions, in those contexts, are considered completely defined.

According to [class.mem.general]/7, in a complete-class context, the class is considered a complete type. It says nothing about whether all function bodies are "visible" and thus, return type deduction has been completed. (I am placing this term in scare quotes because I am not using it in a standard way and will not attempt to give a rigorous definition.)

It's true that in the body of a member function of a class, we can call other functions that may have been declared later in the class, and this is made possible by a combination of [class.mem.general]/7 and the name lookup rules ([basic.lookup.unqual]/8). However, this has nothing to do with the *body* of the callee being "visible". Its definition may even be in another TU, after all.

Being in a complete-class context is clearly not sufficient when there is mutual recursion:

```
struct B {
    static auto e() { return decltype(f())(0); }
    static auto f() { return decltype(e())(0); }
};
```

It's pretty obvious that no compiler will accept the above code. So there must be something more to it than the idea that when you are in a complete-class context, the return types of other member functions that have deduced return types are considered to be known.

In fact, we don't even need mutual recursion. [All compilers reject the following:](https://godbolt.org/z/zoqPebGEz)

```
struct C {
    void f() { int V2 = e(); }
    static auto e() { return 0; }
};
```

---

The foregoing examples suggest that compilers interpret functions defined inside class definitions as follows: hoist the declarations of all class member functions above all definitions (as if all definitions were out-of-line) but maintain the relative ordering between them. That is, the above code is interpreted approximately as if we had a one-pass compiler and the following code:

```
struct C {
    void f();
    static auto e();
};

void C::f() { int V2 = e(); }

auto C::e() { return 0; }
```

When default arguments are involved, where are *they* defined? If the transformation is as follows, the code ought to be acceptable:

```
struct A {
    constexpr static auto e();
    void f(int V1);
};

constexpr auto A::e() { return 0; }
void A::f(int V1 = e()) { int V2 = e(); }  // OK
```

But if a compiler uses the strategy of putting all default arguments first before all function bodies, then we again have a problem:

```
struct A {
    constexpr static auto e();
    void f(int V1);
};

void A::f(int V1 = e());  // ill-formed

constexpr auto A::e() { return 0; }

void A::f(int V1) { int V2 = e(); }
```

The fact that compilers don't accept the OP's code suggests that this latter interpretation corresponds with what is happening internally in those compilers. Why might the Big 4 have all made the choice to put all default arguments first before all function bodies? Well, in C++98, that's a convenient choice. A function body may contain a call to another member function, and that call may use the value of the latter's default argument. But the reverse wasn't true: in C++98, although a default argument's initializer might involve a call to another member function, the *body* of the latter function is not required to have been seen yet (again, it could even be defined in another TU).

I can hear you saying *"hang on, hang on, this is a 'language-lawyer' question! Show me the wording! Where in the standard is this hoisting behaviour specified?"*

It isn't. Because in C++98, there was no need to. The standard merely said that the class is regarded as complete inside function bodies (including ctor-initializers) and default arguments ([class.mem]/2) and let compilers figure out what to do. In C++98, the OP's mental model of "this is a complete-class context, so I have full access to the information about the types of all the members" held.

The introduction of `constexpr` and `auto` in later standards resulted in a wording gap. As the example of `B` above shows, the OP's mental model can no longer hold, and instead the well-formedness of the program seems to depend on considerations of whether default arguments precede function bodies or vice versa, with the standard yielding *no* guidance!

---

However, there is a solution to this problem. It begins with the observation that all compilers accept the [templated version](https://godbolt.org/z/nfhKcePdo):

```
template <class T>
struct D {
    constexpr static auto e() { return 0; }
    void f(int V1 = e()) { }
};
int main() {
    D<void>{}.f();
}
```

Why is it so? It's because members of a class template specialization (NB: `D<void>` is technically a "specialization" in the terminology of the standard, even though the class template `D` has not been "specialized" for `void`) are individually subject to instantiation (which, in general, does not occur at the same time as the instantiation of the class definition itself). When `f()` is called, and only then, is `D<void>::f`'s default argument instantiated, since it is needed at that point (C++20 [temp.inst]/3, [temp.inst]/13). The instantiation of that default argument triggers the instantiation of the definition of `D::e` (C++20 [temp.inst]/4). Everything works out when this code is templated, because the standard requires templated entities to be instantiated only when needed, and this occurs regardless of declaration order; the compiler has to resolve the dependencies, so to speak.

This inconsistency is the subject of [CWG 2335](https://wg21.link/cwg2335). The example there is not quite analogous to the OP's example, because *static* data member initializers are not complete-class contexts. However, the note at the end is very wide-ranging in its implications:

> The consensus of CWG was to treat templates and classes the same by "instantiating" delayed-parse regions when they are needed instead of at the end of the class.

What is a "delayed-parse region" in a non-template class? Presumably, it just means a complete-class context. The insight here is that in order to answer questions such as whether OP's code should work, we need to apply the concept of instantiation to non-templates. A complete-class context, such as a function body or a default argument, should be instantiated only when needed. That means that when this core issue is eventually resolved, OP's code will (presumably) become well-formed by analogy to the templated version.