# error: use of 'decltype(auto) X before deduction of 'auto' (for generated lambda)

Tags: c++, lambda, declval, decltype-auto

I'm trying to hammer down the type of a this-capturing lambda using a special generating member function with decltype(auto). However, the compiler resists to determine the lambda's type for the following contexts that require it, even though it is declare *before*. How can I circumvent this problem?

**EDIT**: My overarching goal is to have a this-capturing lambda as a class member.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:21),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++auto+gen_lambda()+-%3E+decltype(auto)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+%5Bthis%5D()%7B%0A++++++++++++printf(%22Hello!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++entity()%0A++++++++:+++lambda_(gen_lambda())%0A++++%7B%7D%0A%0A++++decltype(std::declval%3Centity%3E().gen_lambda())+lambda_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++entity+e%3B%0A++++e.lambda_()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.825065274151434,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.174934725848566,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

struct entity
{
    auto gen_lambda() -> decltype(auto)
    {
        return [this](){
            printf("Hello!\n");
        };
    }

    entity()
        :   lambda_(gen_lambda())
    {}

    decltype(std::declval<entity>().gen_lambda()) lambda_;
};

int main()
{
    entity e;
    e.lambda_();
}
```

Yields:

```
<source>:17:47: error: use of 'decltype(auto) entity::gen_lambda()' before deduction of 'auto'
   17 |     decltype(std::declval<entity>().gen_lambda()) lambda_;
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

and related.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998126/function-with-deduced-return-type-cannot-be-used-before-it-is-defined)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Interesting answer, I got something out of it. It however doesn't answer how I could work around this. The mentioned answer seems to indicate that if I make gen_lambda() a template, the instantiation can be delayed until a point where the return value can be deduced? How do I implement this in my case?

Comment: You can try to take `gen_lambda` out of the class and make it a free function. By making it a `friend` function and passing a `entity*` as argument you get generally the intended functionality. However in a real application where you want to use `this` in the lambda, you will have a circular dependency problem and you'll be back to having to explicitly specify a type somewhere.

Comment: The type is not deduced until all the declarations have been seen and the function bodies are compiled.

Comment: I think you need to give some more details on your use case before anyone can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate issues here, although at first glance one is templated to conflate them.

First, where you have:

```
decltype(std::declval<entity>().gen_lambda()) lambda_;
```

this entire declaration is not a complete-class context. (If there were a default member initializer for `lambda_`, it would be the only part of the declaration of `lambda_` that is a complete-class context.) Since it's not a complete-class context, you cannot perform a member access into `entity` here, as it is an incomplete class. This can be demonstrated with a much simpler example:

```
struct S {
    int foo() { return 0; }
    decltype(std::declval<S>().foo()) x;
    //                        ^^^^
    // error: member access into incomplete class S
};
```

(Though, for reasons that are unclear to me, GCC does accept the above code.)

Exactly how you should work around this is unclear to me, because you've given no information about what problem you're trying to solve. One obvious technique (though I'm not sure whether it will fit your use case) is to change `gen_lambda` into a static member function:

```
struct entity
{
    template <class T>
    static auto gen_lambda(T* p) {
        return [p] { puts("Hello!"); };
    }

    entity()
        : lambda_(gen_lambda(this))
    {}

    decltype(gen_lambda<entity>(nullptr)) lambda_;
};
```

This solves the issue with incompleteness, but you still might run into the "auto is used before it is deduced" error. As the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998126/function-with-deduced-return-type-cannot-be-used-before-it-is-defined) mentions, the intent is to eventually fix the standard such that this code will be well-formed. In the meantime, two possible workarounds are:

1. Move `gen_lambda` outside the class (e.g. make it a free function that is defined before `S`); or
2. Turn the entire class into a template:

   ```
   template <class U = void>
   struct entity_impl
   {
       template <class T>
       static auto gen_lambda(T* p) {
           return [p] { puts("Hello!"); };
       }

       entity_impl()
           : lambda_(gen_lambda(this))
       {}

       decltype(gen_lambda<entity_impl>(nullptr)) lambda_;
   };

   using entity = entity_impl<>;
   ```

Comment: Good answer. The problem was to have this-capturing lambdas as class members which your last example achieves (many think its impossible). Thanks a lot! Could you add a link to your other answer for future reference?

Comment: [It doesn't work for unique_ptr though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74959360/using-allocator-delete-object-for-member-stdunique-ptr) Interestingly, having an incomplete type as a template parameter works only in some cases.