# Using a custom delete functor (that accesses member) for a member std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, c++pmr

I have a class `entity` that uses a stateful polymorphic allocator and `std::unique_ptr` to manage a resource. Naturally, I have to provide a custom deleter for the unique_ptr that pairs with `allocator_.new_object()` that I pass in the constructor. However, as this deleter must use the same allocator again, I need to access the allocator member from within the deleter. This appears to be quite tricky. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942165/error-use-of-decltypeauto-x-before-deduction-of-auto-for-generated-lambda/74944879#74944879) answer I was able to get this far, but now gcc complains that struct `entity` is incomplete. Any way to get around this?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:54,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:54,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:54,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:54,startLineNumber:12),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cmemory_resource%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astruct+StaticTimer_t%0A%7B%0A++++std::string_view+hello_+%3D+%22Hello+World!!%22%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E+requires+(std::is_pointer_v%3CT%3E)%0Aauto+deleter(T+e)+%7B%0A++++return+%5Be%5D(StaticTimer_t*+p)%7B+e-%3Eget_allocator().delete_object(p)%3B+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++using+allocator_t+%3D+std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator%3Cstd::byte%3E%3B%0A%0A++++auto+get_allocator()+-%3E+allocator_t%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+allocator_%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++entity(allocator_t+allocator+%3D+%7B%7D)%0A++++++++:+++allocator_(+allocator+)+%0A++++++++,+++ptr_(+allocator_.new_object%3CStaticTimer_t%3E(),+deleter(this)+)%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++auto+print()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25s%5Cn%22,+ptr_.get()-%3Ehello_.data())%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++allocator_t+allocator_%3B%0A++++std::unique_ptr%3CStaticTimer_t,+decltype(deleter%3Centity*%3E(nullptr))%3E+ptr_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++entity+e%3B%0A++++e.print()%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:48.825065274151434,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:51.174934725848566,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <type_traits>

struct StaticTimer_t
{
    std::string_view hello_ = "Hello World!";
};

template <typename T> requires (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
auto deleter(T e) {
    return [e](StaticTimer_t* p){ e->get_allocator().delete_object(p); };
}

struct entity
{
    using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

    auto get_allocator() -> allocator_t
    {
        return allocator_;
    }

    entity(allocator_t allocator = {})
        :   allocator_( allocator ) 
        ,   ptr_( allocator_.new_object<StaticTimer_t>(), deleter(this) )
    { }

    auto print()
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr_.get()->hello_.data());
    }

    allocator_t allocator_;
    std::unique_ptr<StaticTimer_t, decltype(deleter<entity*>(nullptr))> ptr_;
};


int main()
{
    entity e;
    e.print();
}
```

Error:

```
<source>:14:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct entity'
   14 |     return [e](StaticTimer_t* p){ e->get_allocator().delete_object(p); };
      |                                   ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:17:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct entity'
   17 | struct entity
      |        ^~~~~~
```

**Note**: I'm looking for a way to get around std::function!

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to get around std::function!` ? Why? What for?

Comment: @KamilCuk Because I'm doing a lot of move operations. The object should be as lightweight as possible. It would be nice if I could NOT have the std::function overhead and work with a bare lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the allocator directly instead of the `entity`. It is all you need and it is complete where you need it to be, unlike `entity`.

```
using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;

auto deleter(allocator_t e) {
    return [e](StaticTimer_t* p) mutable { e.delete_object(p); };
}

entity(allocator_t allocator = {})
    :   allocator_( allocator ) 
    ,   ptr_( allocator_.new_object<StaticTimer_t>(), deleter(allocator_) )
{ }

std::unique_ptr<StaticTimer_t, decltype(deleter(std::declval<allocator_t>()))> ptr_;
```

Alternatively, replace the lambda with a struct (KamilCuk's answer).

Comment: Of course I'm stupid! x_X Thanks!

Comment: I think also you meant std::declval<allocator_t*> as deleter doesn't take an lvalue ref ;)

Comment: Indeed, `allocator_t*`. Updated.

Comment: What I also wonder is if you couldn't just pass allocator_t by value, as for pmr allocators it's just a pointer anyway, thus avoiding one unnecessary indirection. Needs a mutable lambda though as for some reason delete_object() is not const qualified?(!)

Comment: By value is better. It disconnects the deleter from the lifetime of the entity: capturing `entity*` as in the question or `allocator_t*` as in this answer relies on the entity and allocator member staying meaningful. In particular, these are likely to break with entity move operations. By value allocator avoids this problem. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for a way to get around std::function!

Write your own std::function that std::bind-s entity with a operator().

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>

struct StaticTimer_t {
    std::string_view hello_ = "Hello World!";
};

struct entity;

struct entityDeleter {
    entity& e;
    entityDeleter(entity& e) : e(e) {}
    void operator()(StaticTimer_t *p);
};

struct entity {
    using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;
    auto get_allocator() -> allocator_t {
        return allocator_;
    }
    entity(allocator_t allocator = {})
        : allocator_( allocator ) 
        , ptr_(
            allocator_.new_object<StaticTimer_t>(),
            entityDeleter(*this)
        ) {}
    auto print() {
        printf("%s\n", ptr_.get()->hello_.data());
    }
    allocator_t allocator_;
    std::unique_ptr<StaticTimer_t, entityDeleter> ptr_;
};

void entityDeleter::operator()(StaticTimer_t *p) {
    printf("deleter\n");
    e.get_allocator().delete_object(p);
}

int main() {
    entity e;
    e.print();
}
```