# Why would noexcept(true) fail where noexcept works?

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, compiler-bug, noexcept

I have the following code:

```cpp
struct S {
    // conditional noexcept specification which depends on noexceptness of foo()
    void bar() noexcept(noexcept(foo()));
    // conditional noexcept specification (true)
    void foo() noexcept(true);
};
```

Clang rejects this code but GCC allows it (https://godbolt.org/z/nxqa5Tr1x):

```
<source>:2:34: error: exception specification is not available until end of class definition
    2 |     void bar() noexcept(noexcept(foo()));
      |
```

Replacing `noexcept(true)` with `noexcept` is allowed by both compilers.

#### Questions

1. Why would `noexcept(true)` fail but `noexcept` work?
2. Which compiler conforms with the standard, if any?

---

*Note: this example is obviously minimal. My actual use case is that I have a `clear()` member function which is `noexcept` only if `clear_impl()` is `noexcept`, in a custom container.*

Comment: IDK, but `noexcept(noexcept(foo()))` is just ... weird, why would anyone ever write code like that?  And if you write `noexcept(foo ())`, you get a [sensible error message](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uneVmySCO3kDBlih), albeit a [different one](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ECz7zniRSMjUfBAK) from gcc.

Comment: I also think that the question title is a bit misleading (just my $0.02)

Comment: @PaulSanders Your example is not what OP is asking about. `noexcept(noexcept(expression))` is combining [`noexcept` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) with [`noexcept` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) to provide conditional `noexcept` on `bar()` if and only if `foo()` expression is `noexcept`. Not terribly useful here, but that's the nature of MCVE.

Comment: @PaulSanders it's not so easy to put it into words. The honest version would be *"Why would clang disallow a conditional noexcept specfication that depends on noexcept(true) but allow depending on noexcept?"* That's quite a mouthful though.

Comment: Looks like a bug in clang.  If you swap the functions around so `foo` comes first the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/9jKWM98oG.  the noexcept specifier is part of the [complete class context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem.general-7) so clang should accept the code either way

Comment: Interestingly GCC also allows `noexcept(noexcept(bar()))` on the declaration of `foo` making the noexcept specification circular. In this case it interprets it as `noexcept(false)`. [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/sfszc7T5x)

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out my ignorance.  Anyway, moving on...

Comment: @IlCapitano Which leads to nonsense like this: https://godbolt.org/z/rKr1M1TKb

Answer (score 4):

1. There is no reason why `noexcept` and `noexcept(true)` should have different behaviour.
2. This issue appears to be related to CWG issues 1360, 1397, 1890, and 2335.
   A *noexcept-specifier* is a complete-class context. This implies that within a *noexcept-specifier*, `S` is complete (*e.g.* you can see the full list of members of `S`), but it does not imply that within a *noexcept-specifier*, you have access to information that is in later complete-class contexts. In some complete-class contexts, some compilers don't even let you access information that is in earlier complete-class contexts of a different kind, and the wording is not clear enough to say for sure that this is a compiler bug. I explain in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74035315/481267).