# C++20 error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, c++20

Standalone constexpr variable and function can be used as a template argument in both gcc and clang. I am having a hard time understanding why it does not work inside a class.
Below is my snippet, though you can play with it on godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/GxffrPjaj

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <span>

static constexpr size_t max_length = std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits10 + 2 + 1;

constexpr size_t MaxLength() noexcept {
    return std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits10 + 2 + 1;
}

size_t some_function1(std::span<const char, max_length> buf) {
    return buf.size(); // not the real code, but for demo
}

size_t some_function2(std::span<const char, MaxLength()> buf) {
    return buf.size(); // not the real code, but for demo
}

class SomeClass {
    static constexpr size_t class_max_length = std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits10 + 2 + 1;
    constexpr static size_t ClassMaxLength() noexcept {
        return std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits10 + 2 + 1;
    }

    size_t some_function1(std::span<const char, class_max_length> buf) {
        return buf.size(); // not the real code, but for demo
    }

    size_t some_function2(std::span<const char, ClassMaxLength()> buf) {
        return buf.size(); // not the real code, but for demo
    }
};
```

Everything works as standalone functions but fails when I wrapped them in a class, why?

GCC Error:

```
-std=c++20 -O3
123
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x86-64 gcc 12.1 - cached
<source>:30:63: error: 'static constexpr size_t SomeClass::ClassMaxLength()' called in a constant expression before its definition is complete
   30 |     size_t some_function2(std::span<const char, ClassMaxLength()> buf) {
      |                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
<source>:30:63: note: in template argument for type 'long unsigned int'
<source>:30:27: error: 'std::buf' has not been declared
   30 |     size_t some_function2(std::span<const char, ClassMaxLength()> buf) {
      |                           ^~~
<source>: In member function 'size_t SomeClass::some_function2(int)':
<source>:31:16: error: 'buf' was not declared in this scope
   31 |         return buf.size(); // not the real code, but for demo
      |                ^~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Clang Error:

```
<source>:30:49: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
   30 |     size_t some_function2(std::span<const char, ClassMaxLength()> buf) {
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:30:49: note: undefined function 'ClassMaxLength' cannot be used in a constant expression
<source>:22:29: note: declared here
   22 |     constexpr static size_t ClassMaxLength() noexcept {
      |                             ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: I don't know the exact rules that makes it ok in this case but a workaround could be to make the member function into a member variable - in form of a lambda: `inline constexpr static auto ClassMaxLength = [] { return std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::digits10 + 2 + 1; };` - [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/7xKbzYGvo)

Comment: It does not work because a member function definition is not complete inside its own class (member function bodies are all processed after the class definition is complete). One solution is to split the class in two, [see](https://godbolt.org/z/cM4afKb41)

Comment: In-class static variable works just fine. It's only the function that doesn't, but the error kinda tells you why.

Comment: Dupes: [constexpr not working if the function is declared inside class scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493652/constexpr-not-working-if-the-function-is-declared-inside-class-scope) and [constexpr initializing static member using static function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522399/constexpr-initializing-static-member-using-static-function)

Comment: As the downvote button says: "this question does not shows any research effort". Have you tried "searching and then researching" on the web. I got the many dupes for this just on the first search.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to [CWG1890](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1890.html). Basically, it has to do with the fact that implementations behave as if the declarations of member functions in a class are hoisted above all the definitions (so that each definition will see the class as being complete). In this case the result is that the definition of `ClassMaxLength`, from the compiler's point of view, is somewhere after the closing brace of the class definition. This isn't really how things *should* work, but the current standard is not clear enough about this issue. I give more explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74035315/481267).

The fix, oddly enough, is to convert `SomeClass` into a template.